# how to use global variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm very new to python and I would like some help with declaring a global widget label.

```
def leftClick(event):
    global label1

    #the event is called when the 'leftClick' function is used
    #thus, displaying the color of the font

    label1=Label(text=event.widget.cget("fg"),bg=event.widget.cget("fg"))
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=S)

def rightClick(event):
    global label1
    #same goes for 'rightClick' def function but it displays the background of the buttons

    label1=Label(text=event.widget.cget("bg"),bg=event.widget.cget("bg"))
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=S)

    #since its outside the class, we refer to widgets inside the class with event.widget
```

'label1' is not defined in the global scope

Comment: What is a "_global widget label_"?

Comment: the Label is declared as a global variable

Comment: Your Label is assigned to variable `label1`, but you declare `label` as the global variable. Those are two different variables.

Comment: okay, so I just made the adjustment, and its giving me this error: 'label1' is not defined in the global scope

Comment: You have to define it `global` in each function where it is used.

Comment: Your posted code should not generate the mentioned exception.  There should be somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you indicate `label1` exists at the global level (outside the function), but it is never actually declared there.

It's just a warning, but to remove it, add `label1 = None` above (outside) the functions.

```
label1 = None
def leftClick(event):
    global label1  # no warning
    ......
```